# Scrapy – cannot store scraped values in a file

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to crawl the web in order to find blogs with Polish or Poland in their titles. I have some problems at the very beginning: my spider is able to scrape my website's title, but doesn't store it in a file when running

```
scrapy crawl spider -o test.csv -t csv blogseek
```

Here are my settings:
spider

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from polishblog.items import PolishblogItem

class BlogseekSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'blogseek'
    start_urls = [
          #'http://www.thepolskiblog.co.uk',
          #'http://blogs.transparent.com/polish',
          #'http://poland.leonkonieczny.com/blog/',
          #'http://www.imaginepoland.blogspot.com' 
          'http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet'
          ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),

    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        i = PolishblogItem()
        i['titre'] = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        #i['domain_id'] = sel.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').extract()
        #i['name'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').extract()
        #i['description'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').extract()
        return i
```

items.py

```
# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PolishblogItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    titre = Field()
    #description = Field()
    #url = Field()
    #pass
```

When I run

```
scrapy parse --spider=blogseek -c parse_item -d 2 'http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet'
```

I get the title as scraped. So what's the point? I'd bet it's a silly one but couldn't find the issue. Thanks!

EDIT: maybe there is an issue with feedback. When I run with those settings.py:

```
# Scrapy settings for polishblog project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only the most important settings by
# default. All the other settings are documented here:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#

BOT_NAME = 'polishblog'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['polishblog.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'polishblog.spiders'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'damien thiriet (+http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet)'

COOKIES_ENABLED = False
RETRY_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_DELAY=0.25
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True
DEPTH_LIMIT=3

#stockage des resultats
FEED_EXPORTERS='CsvItemExporter'
FEED_URI='titresblogs.csv'
FEED_FORMAT='csv'
```

I get an error message

```
File /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py, line 196, in_load_components
conf.update(self.settings[setting_prefix])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I installed scrapy that way

```
pip2.7 install Scrapy
```

Was I wrong? The doc recommands `pip install Scrapy` but then I would have python3.4 dependencies installed, I bet this is not the point

EDIT #2:

Here are my logs

```
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.2 started (bot: polishblog)
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'polishblog.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'stdout:', 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3, 'RETRY_ENABLED': False, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['polishblog.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'polishblog', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'USER_AGENT': 'damien thiriet (+http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet)', 'LOG_FILE': '/tmp/scrapylog', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25}
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: RobotsTxtMiddleware, HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [blogseek] INFO: Spider opened
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [blogseek] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [blogseek] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.normalesup.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2014-06-10 11:00:15+0200 [blogseek] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet/> from <GET http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet>
2014-06-10 11:00:16+0200 [blogseek] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet/> (referer: None)
2014-06-10 11:00:16+0200 [blogseek] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-06-10 11:00:16+0200 [blogseek] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 737,
     'downloader/request_count': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 6187,
     'downloader/response_count': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 10, 9, 0, 16, 166865),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 10, 9, 0, 15, 334634)}
2014-06-10 11:00:16+0200 [blogseek] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: `FEED_EXPORTERS` [should be a dict](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exporters), not a string. And usually you don't change it's value if you don't customize the output. Also, the command should read `scrapy crawl blogseek -o test.csv -t csv`, not `scrapy crawl spider -o test.csv -t csv blogseek`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read the `FEED_EXPORTERS` well enough. After commenting any FEED line in settings, error disappeared, but using the proper way `scrapy crawl spider blogseek -o test.csv -t csv` unfortunately didn't solve the problem: the csv file is still empty…

Comment: you shouldnt user "spider" in your command, just `scrapy crawl blogspeek -o test.csv -t csv`

Comment: you are right. Unfortunately, it is a mistake I made in the command, not in my console (did not copied/pasted it). And `scrapy crawl blogseek -o test.csv -t csv` did not work. I will add logs in my post.

Comment: Ok. Looking at your logs, it seems your `SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/')` will not match any link in `http://www.normalesup.org/~dthiriet/`. You could use a broader catch-all `SgmlLinkExtractor()` to start with

Comment: setting rules to SgmlLinkExtractor() gave an error message, commenting out rules did not result in any improvement. One hint might be some troubles with unicode, because using `scrapy parse` I get `Scraped Items: [{'titre': [u"Lieux d'histoire, lieux de mémoire en Pologne"]}]`

Comment: File /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py, line 83, in _compile_rules
    self._rules = [copy.copy(r) for r in self.rules]
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence

Comment: Try `rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),

    )`. `rules` must be an iterable

Comment: It works! Many many thanks for following this thread and giving me the proper answer!